# V8, run-tests.py fails

Tags: javascript, v8

When I compile v8, following https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Building-from-Source run-tests.py fails with the error message:

```
Error: Failure: expected <11/11/1500>, found <12/10/1500>.
    at fail (/.../v8/v8/test/intl/assert.js:105:9)
    at assertEquals (/.../v8/v8/test/intl/assert.js:114:5)
    at /Users/holmeshe/.../v8/v8/test/intl/date-format/format-test.js:50:1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are 2 bugs in the date-format/format-test.js:
1. in javascript, month starts from 0,
2. UTC time should be used to create the date object.

So the assertation should be modified to:

```
assertEquals('12/11/1500', dtf.format(new Date(Date.UTC(1500,11,11,12,0,0))));
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really belong on StackOverflow, I think...

You can file a bug at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/list. Note that all tests are passing fine on V8's [buildbots](https://build.chromium.org/p/client.v8/console) (and, I just checked, on my machine too), so please include all information that might be helpful for determining what's different on your machine (which revision did you check out? On which OS? What timezone is your machine in? Anything else you can think of?).

If you have a suggested fix, please follow the [Contribution Guidelines](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Contributing).

Comment: Make sense. I tried removing the thread but it is not removable after there are some answers posted. Anyway, I will work it out from the mail list as suggested. Thanks a lot for the advice.